# Poisson distribution question why my formula is off and I have to multiply by 100,000?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> Observations at a certain large company that on average, there is a
>   server outage every 6 months. What is the probability of getting
>   through a year without any server outage at all?

I solved this question as so.

There are `12` months in a year

We are looking for the probability of no outages in a year which is `P(0 outages)`.

Poisson Formula

$12^0$*$e^{-12}$/0!

This is where I get a very small result which I multiply by `100,000`
= 6.144... * $10^{-6}$

final result = `0.6144`

I am not sure why I am multiplying by 100,000 Its just what makes seance to me which gives a result that could make seance.

Terrible way to go about it but I am struggling to understand how to approach this question?

Comment: Typo in the question :) thanks

Comment: You need to assume something about the probability distribution.  [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) seems like a natural choice (though other things are possible).

Comment: Its a question from a collage assignment which I have been trying to answer fr a few days, its based on the Poisson formula

Comment: So, use that.   If the expected number of outages in $6M$ is $1$ then the expected number in $12M$ is $2$.   Now just use the standard formula.

Comment: yes I thought this but it states `What is the probability of getting through a year without any server outage at all?` This would be P(2 outages)

Comment: Well, it's your notation but I would think that most people would interpret $P(2\,\text {outages})$ to mean "the probability of getting $2$ outages.".  Instead, one wants the probability of getting $0$ out of a Poisson process of mean $2$.  That's just $e^{-2}$.

Comment: No, you're mixing up the parameter of the variable, which is the rate (2 per year), and the number to be reached in the actual question (0).

Comment: If you have the formula at hand, the rate is $\lambda$ and the number to be reached usually denoted by a latin letter (oftentimes it will be $k$).

Comment: I know the formula I am just confused what numbers to plug into it  λ = `The average number of successes` which here is 0 as it is the successful out come we are looking for?

Comment: $2^{0}$ * $e^{-2}$/0! = .13

Comment: @ Arnaud Mortier: Is this the right answer final :) ?